# Solid State Lattice accuracy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

If everything is always moving when there is some heat in the nearby. I mean that every atom in your bulk is constantly beating upwards and downwards and so on. Why is then the fixed points lattice model correct also when we are far from O K ?? Or only the experiments performed at 0 K are suitable for this theoretical model ??

Comment: Because those thermal movements are much smaller than inter-atomic spacings. Yes, in real solid state physics one worries about that. But basically up to the melting point they remain fairly small. The solid doesn't melt because it shakes itself apart.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!

Comment: But if those movements are so small why the free electrons have so many problems when propagating through the material ?? If there is plenty of empty space it should be easier for them to pass through the bulk without almost heating it up, without almost any crash. ???

Comment: Electrons are not simple billard balls. The way they propagate through a crystal is completely different than classical particles. They can slide through a periodic structure completely frictionless, but get scattered from lattice imperfections or vibrations.